# Buttons not appearing in the correct div on hover of image

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML page structure:

```
<div class="col-md-7 col-xs-9" style="margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px; width:870px;">
          <div class="user_details_panel"> 
                <div id="profile_pic"> 
                   <!-- Other content here -->
                </div>
          </div>
          <div id="userposts_panel">
                <div id="userposts_panel">
                   <table> 
                     <tr><?php
                         // php query leading to this echo ...   
                                echo "<td>
                                        <div class='photos'>
                                            <a href='$photo_url' target = '_blank'><img src='$photo_url'/></a>";
                                            if ($user == $username){    
                                            echo "
                                                <a href='inc/change_dp.php'><input class='update' type='button' value='Make Display Picture' /></a>
                                                <a href='inc/delete_photo.php'><input class='delete' type='button' value='Delete' /></a>";
                                            } echo "
                                        </div>
                                    </td>";
                                echo "<style>
                                    .photos:hover img{
                                        opacity:0.5;
                                    }
                                    .photos:hover input {
                                        display: block;
                                    }
                                    .photos input {
                                        position:absolute;
                                        display:none;
                                    }
                                    .photos input.update {
                                        position: absolute;
                                        top:0;
                                        right:0;
                                    }
                                    .photos input.delete {
                                        top:0;
                                        left:0;
                                    }
                                    </style>";
                            </tr>
                        </table>
```

Now, each single image is shown in the `.photos` div (see echo). The `photos` div has no CSS applied to it on its on, just the styling shown above.

I expect these buttons to appear on the top right and top left, as specified in the `<style>`:

```
<a href='inc/change_dp.php'><input class='update' type='button' value='Make Display Picture' /></a>
<a href='inc/delete_photo.php'><input class='delete' type='button' value='Delete' /></a>";
```

The buttons should appear top left, top right, within the `.photos` div on hover. But for some reason, the buttons are appearing in the top corners of the `userposts_panel` div, which has the following CSS:

```
#userposts_panel{
    margin:0 auto;
    min-height: 250px;
    height: auto;
    text-align:left;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    border-left: 1px solid #E1E3E4;
}
```

Not quite sure why this is happening?

Comment: Ehm, are you really echoing the <style> element inside a <tr>? In that case, validate your output. Anyway. can you post the resulting html? Preferably as a snippet here in the question.

Comment: @MrLister - Yes, it works the same when I place the styles in a CSS file?

Comment: @MrLister - Sorry, not quite sure what you mean by "resulting HTML"?

Comment: You have posted the PHP here. And it's not easy to debug a partial PHP program, since we don't know what the values of the variables are. So can you take the resulting webpage (as seen in the browser) and copy the relevant part of the source in here; use the View Source command.

Comment: @MrLister - I have made a quick fiddle demonstrating the issue here - https://jsfiddle.net/czgj9t65/ - As you can see, I need the buttons to on hover, appear within the red div.

Comment: @MrLister - Apply `display:relative` to which div? the `userposts_panel`? Because I have applied it to the `userposts_panel` and I see no changes? And because I needed the input type submit to call a php script? I realize it definitly isn't the best way to go about this, but I will change it - thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `position` rather than `display`. My bad. I'll type it up as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display elements absolutely in a container, use `position:relative` on the container; that way the child elements will know where to position themselves relatively to.

```css
#userposts_panel {
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 250px;
  height: auto;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #E1E3E4;
}
.photos:hover img {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.photos:hover input {
  display: block;
}
.photos input {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
.photos input.update {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.photos input.delete {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.photos {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position:relative; /* added */
}
```

```html
<div id="userposts_panel">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="photos">
          <a href='#' target='_blank'>
            <img src='#' />
          </a>
          <a href='inc/change_dp.php'>
            <input class='update' type='button' value='Make Display Picture' />
          </a>
          <a href='inc/delete_photo.php'>
            <input class='delete' type='button' value='Delete' />
          </a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

You have an error, by the way: it's not allowed to put a `<button>` inside an `<a>`, ever. (Or, any interactive element inside another interactive element.) This will play havoc with the user interface and the event handling inside the nested elements. (Note that it may work the way you intended with the browser you've tested, but that doesn't mean it works the same way in all browsers!)

Comment: Thank you for all your help. Everything is working now. Also as mentioned, I will fix that <a> right away. Thank again.